# Collecting data in mysql by logstash

Tags: logstash

in my mysql eg 2 table in a relationship with each other like this

```
product1 : [{id:1,name:abc1},{id:2,name:abc2},{id:3,name:abc3}]

product2 : [{id:1,product1_id:2,status:like},{id:2,product1_id:2,status:
dislike},{id:1,product1_id:1,status:like}]
```

how I can use to gather information logstash in my mysql examples to get a data structure like this in elasticsearch

```
_souce : {
   "id" : "1"
   "name" : "abc1"
   "status" : [
       "like"
   ]
}
```

....

```
_souce : {
   "id" : "2"
   "name" : "abc2"
   "status" : [
       "like",
       "dislike"
   ]
}
```

..

tôi biết rằng phải cấu hình trong file logstash.conf 
và đây là một đoạn cấu hình trong đó

```
jdbc_driver_library => "path/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar"

jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:9200/abc"

jdbc_user => "***"

jdbc_password => "***"

statement => "SELECT product1.id,product1.name,product2.status FROM product1 LEFT JOIN product2 ON product1.id = product2.product1_id"
```

but the data is not like I want to hope that I will get the answer

I am not limited in english hope people can understand I am wanted gi.Thanks

Comment: You need a solution like this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/36982705/4604579 which uses `GROUP_CONCAT` to "join" all like/dislike for a given product.

Comment: thank you I also thought about it and LogStash Filter - Aggregate also helps me the same thing but I wanted more than £ 2 and it really complicated to make me want to configure axis