# Is it a good idea to boost a Oracle Sql database with elasticsearch

Tags: database, elasticsearch, database-design, architecture, oracle10g

I'm currently working on a classic MVC project that is handling files.

I have a research screen in my application that is multi-criteria.
The resulting request is making like 5 or 6 unions and joins over a big database ( > 5 millions records ).
We improved the request with a DBA but the result isn't satisfying.

I was wondering if it's a good idea to back the database with elasticsearch.
I'm thinking about indexing each field of thes criterias of that screen in elasticsearch in order to retrieve datas easily.

I would like to know if somebody had already encounter this problem before and how did you solved it.

Thanks.

Comment: These answers should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477095/elasticsearch-replication-of-other-system-data/34477639#34477639 + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915428/how-to-setup-elasticsearch-index-structure-with-multiple-entity-bindings/36982705#36982705

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the answer. These posts show how to set it up but don't explain  if the choice is wise considering the performances of the applications.

Comment: It's clearly a wise choice, use the technology for what it's good at: RDBMS to store data, ES to search it ;-)

Comment: I have encountered such a problem before and have solved it completely within Oracle DB, with proper logical table organization. How did I solve it, is outside of scope of this web site and the solution to your particular problem might be completely different from the solution I implemented back then. But all in all, be confident about Oracle DB being good enough to do your multi-criteria searches on its own.