# ElasticSearch Scripting for indexing with data of another document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a tree of documents, each document have a parent document except the root. The root is indirectly the parent of all other.

I can't use the relationnal support of elastic search because there are some limits with the performance, etc.

But I need to research information with data of the child and the parent of a document.

Today this is what I have :

```js
//index/contact/754
{
    "Firstname" : "Arthur",
    "Town" : "Paris",
}

//index/command/1001
{
    "Ref" : "ague001",
    "Parent" : "754"
}

//index/document/5889
{
    "Name" : "Contract",
    "Date" : "01/01/17",
    "Parent" : "1001"
}
```

And I want to have this :

```js
//index/contact/754
{
    "Firstname" : "Arthur",
    "Town" : "Paris",
}

//index/command/1001
{
    "Ref" : "ague001",
    "Parent" : {
        "Firstname" : "Arthur",
        "Town" : "Paris",
    }
}

//index/document/5889
{
    "Name" : "Contract",
    "Date" : "01/01/17",
    "Parent" : {
        "Ref" : "ague001",
        "Parent" : {
            "Firstname" : "Arthur",
            "Town" : "Paris",
        }
    }
}
```

With this, I can easy query the last document by the terms `contract arthur`.

Because of large number of files it's hard to make this while I'm indexing so I search to use an elasticsearch script for doing it. I need a script for indexing a document with data of another document.

May be this is not a good option, if you think of a better way please give me the information. The parent relation of elasticsearch can't be good because a child is in the same shard of the parent. In this case all the document will be in the shard of the root.

Comment: The best way is to denormalize at indexing time. See this answer for some guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915428/how-to-setup-elasticsearch-index-structure-with-multiple-entity-bindings/36982705#36982705

Comment: I'm agree with you, I'm working on but there are performance limitation for the indexing and I try to search the other ways for compare

Comment: What matters most is the performance gain at search time to support your use cases.