# Join two json in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a specific requirement where two json files are in elastic and having a common attribute called "code_type". Like in table we do inner join " where a.code_type=b.code_type" is there any way we can achieve that in elastic search and view data in Kibana?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if terms aggregation is useful for you: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Comment: In general, **INNER JOIN is not possible**, see for instance this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994672/is-there-a-query-similar-to-joins-in-elasticsearch). Great suggestion by @ArchitSaxena, you can add combine terms aggregation with[`top hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html), it might be enough in some cases.