# ElasticSearch Multi Index Query

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin, logstash-configuration

simple question: I have multiple indexes in my elasticsearch engine mirrored by postgresql using logstash. ElasticSearch performs well for fuzzy searches, but now I need to use references within the indexes, that need to be handled by the queries.

```
Index A:
{
  name: "alice",
  _id: 5
} 
...

Index B:
{
  name: "bob",
  _id: 3,
  best_friend: 5
}
...
```

How do I query:

**Get every match of index B with field name starting with "b" and index A referenced by "best_friend" with the name starting with "a"**

Is this even possible with elasticsearch?

Comment: You should think about [denormalizing your data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915428/how-to-setup-elasticsearch-index-structure-with-multiple-entity-bindings/36982705#36982705) to better query it later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's possible: `POST A,B/_search` will query multiple indexes.

In order to match a record from a specific index, you can use [meta-data field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/mapping-index-field.html) `_index`

Below is a query that **gets every match of index B with field name starting with "b" and index A with the name starting with "a"** but not matches a **reference** as you usually do in relational SQL databases. foreign key reference matching (join) in Elastic and every NoSQL is YOUR responsibility AFAIK. refer to [Elastic Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html) to find out the best approach to your needs. Lastly, NoSQL is not SQL, change your mind.

```
POST A,B/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "prefix": {
                  "name": "a"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": "A"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "prefix": {
                  "name": "b"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": "B"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mjalil && Val - I think we will flatten out the data structure..

Comment: Unfortunately the `_index` field doesn't work with Aliases: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23306

Comment: @Airn5475 yes, unfortunately it doesn't support aliases