# Elastic search - Retrieve data from multiple types

Tags: elasticsearch, elassandra

I am working with **elasticsearch** and I have two types which hold my data.

Now I need to retrieve data from both types by using a single query.

**Please see my use case**

I have two types called basic and marks and I saved document as follows

```
myindex/basic
```

> {     "id": "100",    "name": "Tom" }

```
myindex/basic
```

> {     "id": "101",    "name": "John"
>
> }

```
myindex/marks
```

> {     "id": "100",    "mark": "300"
>
> }

```
myindex/marks
```

> {     "id": "101",    "mark": "500" }

Now i need to get the name and mark of a student his id is 100.

Is there any possibility to get result like this.

I came to know that these type of data model is not good for nosql but here i need it as these records are replicated from RDBMS DB.

Any suggestion please and thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with this, but did you tried joining queries? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/joining-queries.html Maybe this helps you somehow.

Comment: @PiotrPradzynski it is the answer

Comment: I strongly suggest denormalizing your data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915428/how-to-setup-elasticsearch-index-structure-with-multiple-entity-bindings/36982705#36982705

Comment: Thank you All, In my case, i need to query data from both types with a single request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query both types in single query by listing them in url

```
POST myindex/basic,marks/_search
```

You can also filter all of them by id

```
POST myindex/basic,marks/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"term": {
          "id": {
            "value": 100
          }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```